# No wireless connection (WiFi problem)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS recently on my laptop and I can't connect to the internet via WiFi.
I've used Wireless Info Script recommended here: [wireles info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
And I got following results: [My results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15374055/)

What should I do to make my WiFi work?

Comment: Yes! It helped me! Thanks a lot! :-D